# Evaluating expressions inside conditionals in org tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Evaluating expressions inside conditionals works in elisp

```lisp
(defun usd(amount currency)
  (if (string= currency "USD")
      amount
    (/ amount 3.75)))

(usd 123 "USD") ; => 123
(usd 123 "SAR") ; => 32.8
```

But doesn't work inside an org table

```
| amount | currency |    USD |
|--------+----------+--------|
|    123 | USD      |    123 |
|     54 | USD      |     54 |
|    223 | SAR      | #ERROR |
|     54 | USD      |     54 |
|     52 | SAR      | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: $3='(usd $1 $2)
```

Why would this error happen? I could solve this problem by having an intermediate column

```
| amount | currency | intermediate |   USD |
|--------+----------+--------------+-------|
|    123 | USD      |            1 |   123 |
|     54 | USD      |            1 |    54 |
|    223 | SAR      |      0.26667 | 59.47 |
|     54 | USD      |            1 |    54 |
|     52 | SAR      |      0.26667 | 13.87 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(if (string= $2 "USD") 1 .26667)::$4=round($1*$3,2)
```

But that makes the table unnecessarily bigger.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: [This is probably a duplicate] The cell entries are passed as strings even when they look like numbers. Try `#+TBLFM: $3='(usd (string-to-number $1) $2)`. You can see what it did if you turn on formula debugging with `C-c {` (use the same key to toggle debugging off).

Comment: Thank you guys. I want to upvote you but I don't see the option.